# how to display Sin[Subscript[\alpha,i]/2] as $s_{\bar{\alpha}_i}$ using e.g., Makeboxes?

Tags: output-formatting, display

Update:
   the following code proposed by Lukas works perfectly. I have tested both fraction or $a/b$ form, both work.  I have revised the code a little bit, to make it more flexible:

```
  MakeBoxes[Sin[Rational[1, 2] Subscript[\[Alpha]_, i_]], 
  StandardForm] := 
 MakeBoxes[Subscript["s", Subscript[Overscript[\[Alpha], _], i]], 
 StandardForm]
MakeBoxes[Cos[Rational[1, 2] Subscript[\[Alpha]_, i_]], 
  StandardForm] := 
 MakeBoxes[Subscript["c", Subscript[Overscript[\[Alpha], _], i]], 
  StandardForm]
```

I learnt that we can use Makeboxes to display Sin[\alpha_i] as $s_{\alpha_i}$ as follows:

```
  (*MakeBoxes[Sin[Subscript[\[Alpha],i_]],StandardForm]:=
 MakeBoxes[Subscript[Subscript["s",\[Alpha]],i],StandardForm]
```

but can't find a way to make Sin[Subscript[[Alpha],i]/2] display as $s_{\bar{\alpha}_i}$,  regardless of in fraction form or in $a/b$ form. I have been looking for this for quite a long time, but with no luck. I checked the documentation, but can't understand how Makeboxes works, especially in this context.

Could someone help to produce such a way so that it can take effect on both calculations involving fraction form or $a/b$ form? It'd be even better if some explanation on how to do it is provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you are facing is that the [`FullForm`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullForm.html) of `x/2` changes upon evaluation, combined with the [`HoldAllComplete`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldAllComplete.html) attribute of [`MakeBoxes`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MakeBoxes.html):

```
Hold[a/2]//FullForm
(* Hold[Times[a,Power[2,-1]]] *)

a/2//FullForm
(* Times[Rational[1,2],a] *)
```

Note how $a\cdot2^{-1}$ changes to $a\cdot\frac 12$ when allowed to evaluate. As mentioned above, this leads to problems due to the `HoldAllComplete` attribute of `MakeBoxes`: You are defining a rule for the form you are inputting, which means it will not be applied to the evaluated form:

```
MakeBoxes[Sin[Subscript[α, i] / 2], StandardForm] =
  MakeBoxes[Subscript[s, Subscript[Overscript[α, _], 2]], StandardForm]

Sin[Subscript[\[Alpha], i]/2]
```

> $\sin(\frac\alpha2)$

```
HoldForm[Sin[Subscript[\[Alpha], i]/2]]
```

> $s_{\bar{\alpha}_2}$

To fix this, you need to define a formatting rule for the evaluated form:

```
MakeBoxes[Sin[Rational[1, 2] Subscript[α, i]], StandardForm] = 
  MakeBoxes[Subscript[s, Subscript[Overscript[α, _], 2]], StandardForm]

Sin[Subscript[\[Alpha], i]/2]
```

> $s_{\bar{\alpha}_2}$

Alternatively, you can also inject the evaluated form into `MakeBoxes`:

```
With[
  {evaluated = Sin[Subscript[α, i] / 2]},
  MakeBoxes[evaluated, StandardForm] =
   MakeBoxes[Subscript[s, Subscript[Overscript[α, _], 2]], StandardForm]
]

Sin[Subscript[\[Alpha], i]/2]
```

> $s_{\bar{\alpha}_2}$

Note that using [`Evaluate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Evaluate.html) would not work, since [`HoldAllComplete`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldAllComplete.html) prevents any and all forms of evaluation, including `Evaluate` and up-values.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, which helps me solve the problem successfully. Notice that I made a typo in the subscript, I wanted it to be "i". I have revised it, and revised your code a little bit, to make it more flexible. Thanks!